# Sinch Integration in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, sinch

I'm trying to integrate [sinch](http://sinch.com) into my Swift project using `cocoapods`

```
#platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'auxilium' do
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
  pod 'SinchRTC'
end
```

The pod installation work fine but when I try to import the library `import Sinch` I get this error

> No such module "Sinch"

Any helps here what I've missed !!! thanks

**Plus**
I've noticed that my pod doesn't exist in targets :
[image]

Comment: navigate to your project directory and pod update , ping me it doesn't fix your issue

Comment: try to restart xcode

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I've tried both solutions already none of them work.

Comment: xcworkspace , this should be opened , are you doing the same or opening xcodeproj?

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Really !!!

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari I know that already, thanks for the help

Comment: can you share you import code its objC or swift? Check your config as well, when your run pod install does it give you warnings about not able to set config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that was that I didn't add the `Bridging-Header.h`

```
#import <Sinch/Sinch.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to import

```
#import<Sinch/Sinch.h>
```

You can directly access example for below code Without importing like below code:

```
let config = Sinch()
```

for reference you can check here: [No Such Module "Sinch" Xcode 9.1 Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843107/no-such-module-sinch-xcode-9-1-swift-4?noredirect=1#comment82650618_47843107)

Comment: ping me if any one found any issue