# Can sinch api be used with swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Can we use sinch api to create an instant message app in swift? I tried to import sinch framework in a swift app but after importing I could not import the sinch class into my application. Help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CocoaPod to install your framework, might be easier.

[how to install Pod](https://cocoapods.org/)

in your podfile

```
target 'YourApp' do
  pod 'SinchRTC ', '~> 3.1.0'
end
```

open the YourApp.xcworkspace with xcode.
Now, In your file you will just have to import something like

`import Sinch`

and it might be good.

CocoaPod is really usefull for dependencies. it help you to install / uninstall framework very easily. it's also very nice when you work in team.

Note : change YourApp by your target name

Comment: I followed the steps but I cannot do 'import Sinch' into my project file .

Comment: My bad, I just realized it was an Objective-C framework, so you'll need to create a bridging-header in order to make everything work.

Create a `brindging-header.h` file, like this one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146336/sinch-integration-in-swift-project)