# No Such Module "Sinch" Xcode 9.1 Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, sinch

This question may be duplicate of this "[Sinch Integration in swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146336/sinch-integration-in-swift-project)" But i am doing all these steps But getting same error " No such module 'Sinch'.  Below steps i have followed please check and let me know if i missed any steps or need to add??

I have Added this in my podfile:
    pod 'SinchRTC'

Pod installed successfully with no warning: [image]

Added this in Bridge-Header file:

```
#import<Sinch/Sinch.h>
```

Note: Update pod more then 10 times and restarted xcode multiple times.[image]

Comment: try to clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: Tried more then 50 times from yeseterday

Comment: did you tried to clear Derived Data?

Comment: Could you Please show your " Bridge-Header" file?

Comment: did you added use_frameworks! in pod file

Comment: Bridge-Header already mentioned in question

Comment: used use_framworks too in pod file

Comment: @S.Bharti, Will you please let me know which swift tutorial you were followed?

Comment: @Amanpreet check sinch document it should be there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done same thing with cocoapod and Bridge-Header and what I found is you don't need to `import Sinch` in your header.

You can directly use it without importing. Check below screenshot:

[image]

Pod File:

```
target 'test' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'
pod 'SinchRTC'

  # Pods for test

end
```

Bridge-Header File:

```
#import <Sinch/Sinch.h>
```

Check [Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T3-9ZqcftZFe71P7YXdtwKnsrOLz9cVN/view?usp=sharing) Project for more info.

Comment: Can you give me example code for video call in sinch(Swift) or i have to post another question??

Comment: You need to ask another question because I never worked with sinch.

Comment: No problem. Thanks