# Getting 'Include of non-modular header' while try to import Sinch in framework target

Tags: ios, sinch

I'm trying to import Sinch to my framework target in Xcode.

It work fine with

> ```
> pod 'SinchRTC'
> ```

and

> ```
> #import <Sinch/Sinch.h>
> ```

in Project-Bridging-Header.h in my main project target

but when I try to do the same thing with framework target
by add

> ```
> #import <Sinch/Sinch.h>
> ```

to framework umbrella header instead of bridging header.

I get this message

> "Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'MyFramework': "

I did try to set allow modular framework setting to TRUE, but still doesn't work.

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776497/include-of-non-modular-header-inside-framework-module
or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31238761/what-is-an-umbrella-header
on the other hand, maybe umbrella headers wont work. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift/issues/154

Comment: This link help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843107/no-such-module-sinch-xcode-9-1-swift-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843107/no-such-module-sinch-xcode-9-1-swift-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SinchRTC cocoapod 3.12.5 has recently been released, and the Sinch Framework is now packaged as a module framework inside the pod. Please give a try for 3.12.5 (and later versions), and see if the problem is solved. Thanks.